# Every time I restart a specific Windows Service, I have to re-enter logon details

Tags: windows-services

I have set up the Azure Devops build agent running as a Windows service. Every time I restart/start the service I get a popup

> Error 1069 The service did not start due to a logon error

If I go into the service `Log On` settings and re-enter the same credentials, it will now start. Each time I do this I get a popup

> The account  has been granted the Log On As A Service right

But why would this be? It seems like the right is not 'sticking' somehow?

Comment: Find the Service (Admin Tools) and select Properties. In the Login tab, ensure again that you have selected an Admin account to start the service. Then in the Recovery tab, set the First, Second and Subsequent tries to restart the service. See if this helps .

Comment: I _think_ I was somehow entering logon details with the service already running, which meant they were only retained for that session. I've tried explicitly stopping it and entering details before starting... does this make sense?

Comment: I usually set service as I described before starting it. That may not work here for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to a group policy overwriting your local policy. Please see ["Why does my Windows Service keep forgetting its password?"](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/windows-service-forgets-password/) for the details.